Converting time from utc in linux results in unspecified kind
I am hosting the .NET core app on Linux and I have an issue when converting UTC time to some other zone, the time has an unspecified kind. I found similar questions where issue was regarding timezones on Linux, and they were suggesting following code, but it doesn't work:
string tz = TZConvert.WindowsToIana("Central Europe Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(tz);

DateTime currentTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tzi); // kind is unspecified

I tried using timezones from IANA TZ db

What else do you expect? Its neither local nor UTC afterwards. And that is the only distinction DateTime makes. If its neither local nor UTC its unspecified.

What do you mean? I passed timezone info in which I want to cast, the similar code in windows environment sets the correct kind

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?view=net-8.0 see the possible values for the DateTIme.Kind

And from docu for TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc "The date and time in the destination time zone. Its Kind property is Utc if destinationTimeZone is Utc; otherwise, its Kind property is Unspecified. "

You are right... but what is the way to get kind also?

Maybe add to the question for what you need it. I know it feels weird to not have a "Zoned" DateTime but typically its not really needed. So state for what its needed and we have ideas then where to go or look at.

timezones from IANA TZ db where did you find them? If you used NodaTime why not just use the library types instead of trying to convert anything? Besides, the very point of using IANA timezone names is to not use Windows timezone names. Otherwise you could use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId with the time and Windows timezone name you want

If you want the result to be anything other than UTC you'll have to change the Kind explicitly. .NET can't guess what the developer or end user may consider as local time. The fact you can't just call DateTime.Now or thatDate.ToLocalDateTime()  means the server's timezone isn't the one you want

If you care about offsets, use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime. If you care about timezones use NodaTime and its types.
